# Is there a way to get a imported csv file as a DF to pull out a single row

Tags: python, pandas

Ive imported multiple csv file into a dataframe, and now want to extract a single row from each orignial csv file and then compile them together. Whenever i try to locate the row it says

```
'list' object has no attribute loc'
```

i dont know why it keeps assinging it as a list when ive use `pd.read_csv("filepath")`
thanks

Comment: We cannot help to fix code that you do not show. As a new user, you should read [ask] to know how we expect questions to be asked on SO. Here, you are supposed to show a [mcve] so that we can understand where your problem is and how it could be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for `iloc` property to access a row
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

Dataframes are really good to locate rows by their content and not by their index.

If for example you want the row having a variable ID = "111", you can get it using
df[df["ID"] == 111]